# How can we get file name, sheet name, max rows, and max columns for all Excel files in a folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I am trying to get the file name, sheet name, max rows, and max columns of each sheet in each Excel file. I did some research today on how to use Python to take an inventory of Excel files in a folder. I put together the code below and it seems to get me the file name and sheet name, but it gets stuck on the rows and columns. As I know, the rows and columns are strings, right. I'm trying to accommodate that requirement, but something seems to be off here. Can someone tell me what's wrong here?

```
import openpyxl
import glob
import pandas as pd

inventory = []

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
path = '\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\sample\\*.xlsx'
for f in glob.glob(path):
    print(f)
    inventory.append(f)
    theFile = openpyxl.load_workbook(f)
    sheetnames = theFile.active
    for sheet in sheetnames:
        print(sheet)
        inventory.append(sheet)
        row_count = str(sheet.max_row)
        col_count = str(sheet.max_col)
        inventory.append(row_count)
        inventory.append(col_count)

print(inventory)
```

Comment: `sheetnames = theFile.active` is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate over the worksheets in a workbook, you should use `for sheet in theFile.worksheets`. Your current attempt is actually iterating over all of the rows in your workbook, starting at the active sheet.

`sheet.max_col` is also the incorrect function, use `sheet.max_column`

So your working code is now:

```
import openpyxl
import glob

inventory = []
path = '\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\sample\\*.xlsx'
for f in glob.glob(path):
    # print(f)
    inventory.append(f)
    theFile = openpyxl.load_workbook(f)
    sheetnames = theFile.active

    for sheet in theFile.worksheets:
        # print(sheet)
        inventory.append(sheet)
        row_count = str(sheet.max_row)
        col_count = str(sheet.max_column)
        inventory.append(row_count)
        inventory.append(col_count)

print(inventory)
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks for showing me that!!